# How to skip empty values with rbind.fill or replace them with another value?

Tags: r, dataframe, web-scraping, rbind

first time asking on stack, so apologies for any mistakes in this question.

I am trying to scrape the suspension rates for all California high schools off of https://dq.cde.ca.gov/dataquest/, the public data sight for the California Department of education.

In case my code isn't very clear, let me describe my scraping process. The data I'm interested is on different webpages for each school with the only difference in the various URL's being the school CDS code. So using another dataframe composed of school CDS codes, I substitute the various school CDS codes into the URL, pull the data from the respective tables that schools have on their webpages. If there isn't data for a school in a specific year, no table is pulled up and the scraper will pull in empty values.

The problem I am running into is that when the scraper pulls in empty values (for when no data is found for a school in that year), I'm unable to continue binding scrapped data into my scrape dataframe.

I have two possible ways I think might solve the problem, but haven't been able to figure out the code for either of them.

First, I'm wondering is there a way to have my scraper either skip these school ID codes when the data is not found (and the html_text is then empty) when the values are empty, or to make it so I replace those empty values with NA's?

Secondly, is there a way to use the rbind.fill command where if empty values are found, to turn those into NA's or some other symbol that will represent missing data?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Code

```
#Initial Dataframe
CDS.code = c("01611190130229", "12626870111922", "19643031935618")
school = c("Alameda High", "American Indian Academy", "Mayfair High")
source = data.frame(CDS.code, school)


for (page_result in source$CDS.Code) {
  link = paste0("https://dq.cde.ca.gov/dataquest/dqCensus/DisSuspCount.aspx?year=2020-21&agglevel=School&cds=", page_result," ")

  page = read_html(link)
 
  school_id = page_result
  #Columns for Data
  hs_name = page %>% 
    html_nodes("tr:nth-child(2) a") %>%
    html_text()

  total_suspensions = page %>%
    html_nodes("#ContentPlaceHolder1_grdTotals tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(3)")%>%
    html_text()

    df_schools = rbind.fill(df_schools, data.frame(
    school_id,
    total_suspensions,
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
```

I expected the missing values to be populated with NA's, I've tried replacing empty values with NA and a few other values.

I've also tried to figure out how to make the web scraping portion skip when no value is found, but it's broke each time.

Comment: Two thoughts: 1) populate the data.frame with `school_id, total_suspensions` first and fill with NA values (`data.frame('school_id' = NA, 'total_suspensions' = NA)`) ; 2) check that `page = read_html(link)` returns values prior to trying to append. If there are no values, just either `next` or handle how you want, and if there are values, replace them and then `rbind`

Comment: The "American Indian Academy" schools links not validate. Can you make correction?
https://dq.cde.ca.gov/dataquest/dqCensus/DisSuspCount.aspx?year=2020-21&agglevel=School&cds=12626870111922

Comment: I cant access these sites for some reason. Is it regional locked?

Comment: The "American Indian Academy" code I left in my example text as it's a school that closed in timeframe of when I'm collecting the data. Basically, it's the example of the this problem I'm encountering. 

I don't believe the data is regionally locked, but unsure.

Answer (score 0):

How you can skip over data with empty table with `purrr::possibly()`. If the function encounter empty tables it will produce `NA` instead of summing the third column.

```
library(rvest)
library(httr2)
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
```

Sample data

```
source = tibble(
  CDS.code = c("01611190130229", "12626870111922", "19643031935618"),
  school = c("Alameda High", "American Indian Academy", "Mayfair High")
)

# A tibble: 3 × 2
  CDS.code       school                 
  <chr>          <chr>                  
1 01611190130229 Alameda High           
2 12626870111922 American Indian Academy
3 19643031935618 Mayfair High
```

Scraper function

```
get_susp <- function(cds_code) {
  cat("SCraping CDS:", cds_code, "\n")
  str_c(
    "https://dq.cde.ca.gov/dataquest/dqCensus/DisSuspCount.aspx?year=2020-21&agglevel=School&cds=",
    cds_code
  ) %>%
    request() %>%
    req_perform() %>%
    resp_body_html() %>%
    html_table() %>% 
    nth(8) %>% # Pluck the 8th table
    mutate(across(3, as.numeric)) %$% # Convert it to numeric 
    sum(TotalSuspensions, na.rm = TRUE) # Sum of total suspension
}
```

Create a new column with the sum of total suspension for that High School

```
source %>%  
  mutate(total_susp = map_dbl(
    CDS.code, possibly(get_susp, otherwise = NA_integer_)
  ))

# A tibble: 3 × 3
  CDS.code       school                  total_susp
  <chr>          <chr>                        <dbl>
1 01611190130229 Alameda High                     5
2 12626870111922 American Indian Academy         NA
3 19643031935618 Mayfair High                     0
```

Comment: Sorry, I was unable to follow the scraper function you wrote out, so is this trying to pull directly from the various tables on DataQuest and when that data isn't there it will return as an NA?

Comment: @Jarvis14 That is correct. For the sample data you have attached - the code works. What went wrong on your end?